# Meta-analysis with different scales

Tags: statistical-significance, meta-analysis, effect-size

Say I want to do a meta-analysis testing different joinery methods reported from independent labs. The problem is that Lab A applied the force at 45 degrees while Lab B applied the force and 180 degrees. Though the relative force required to break the joint is the same (the same joints that were strongest in Lab A were also strongest in Lab B) the absolute pounds/inch are different simply because the force was applied in different directions.

How should I go about doing a meta-analysis on the force required to break the joints on the joints tested in Lab A and Lab B when the values are different magnitudes.

Here are some ideas I had, but these could be off:

1. Standardize (or z-score) the force reported.
2. As opposed to doing meta-analysis on the force do some kind of ranking meta-analysis. I am not sure if this is even a thing.